# currency and value always in the same line

Tags: sapui5, currency

i am using the currency control in a responsive table and the currency of the value pops in when the value exeeds a certin width (depends on the screen). I want them to be always displayed in the same line. Ofc i could use the width property to make the column bigger, but that doesnt seem to work out when opening the app on mobile devices.

Any ideas?

[image: visual example]

Thx in advance, Eric

Answer (score 1):

According to the fiori guidelines there is only one option: move other columns to the pop-in-area to save more space for your column (https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/#responsiveness-and-adaptiveness)

But I would be happy for you if you find a "smarter" solution then adapting column width or using pop-in-area or hiding columns on mobile devices. At the end I believe that full responsivness cannot be achieved with fixed widths ... so working with pop-in-area and hiding columns if possible is the only solution.

Comment: thanks for confirming, actually on mobile it is fine because, it s the sama for every column, just on desktop some are in the same line some not :(, just if i use the width property the mobile version gets messed up, i ll proberly end up hiding some columns and adding a table perso dialog so the user can get them back

Comment: i am going to leave the question open a lil while longer, in the hope someone has an other solution

Comment: sure, hoping the same. But also from my experience, using a non-flexible mechanism ends up in mess on at least one device somewhere on the planet :)